# Selecting certain rows in excel from a large number of rows

Tags: excel

My time series data is saved in excel, which has `120000` rows. I want to select several thousand rows from it to copy and paste into different excel files. I know that I can use `Shitft+down\up` to select rows\columns. However, it's not practical in my case owing to a large number of rows to select. Moreover, using `Shift+Ctrl` will select all the rows or columns at a time. Is there any solution without adding extra plugins in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the name box (just google "Excel name box", if you are not sure where it is)

1. Click in the Name Box.
2. Type in the range that interests you e.g.

- "20:40" will select rows from 20 to 40
- "A3:C29" will select a range from A3 to C29

3. Hit Enter.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is a good answer, but a screenshot rather that enforcing to search for a part of your answer will be better.